# Cassandra Large Partitions

Tags: cassandra

We have a table with partition key as user_id + bucket (yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm). Also clustering key is time_uuid (same from which above bucket value is derived).

1. Previous -  We chop the last value in minutes `hh-mm` --> so `2023-11-09-23-17` become `2023-11-09-23-10`. Other way to say all the user activities in the last 10 mins goes in the same partition.
2. Since this was causing the partition size to grow upto 1 GB for high volume customers. Change the bucket to 1 min window. Other way to say all the user activities in the last 1 min goes in the same partition.

Question:

Before we have one big partition ~ 700+ Mib. Now we have multiple (3) partitions >100 Mib. I also see increased number of timeouts after the change was rollout, specially during compaction. I know the design needs a change but my naive question is it is worse to have 3 partition with > 100 Mib compared to one partition of >700 Mib? Since I am seeing increased timeout since the changes are rollout.

```
| Partition_Key  |  No Of Rows.  | Size (in MiB) |
|:----           |:------:       | -----:        |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-21'  | 21822    | ~89.075 MiB  |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-22'  | 19064    | ~77.346 MiB  |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-23'  | 14255    | ~58.100 MiB  |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-24'  | 16319    | ~66.297 MiB  |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-25'  | 25378    | ~101.179 MiB |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-26'  | 28281    | ~114.799 MiB |
| user_id = 1 AND bucket = '2023-11-09-15-27'  | 28943    | ~117.993 MiB |
```

Comment: what compaction strategy do you use? is it ttld or deleted ever?

Comment: TTL is 21 
AND gc_grace_seconds = 172800 AND 
org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy